# Bought a Harley, had my father co sign. He's listed as primary

Tags: loans, co-sign

I bought a Harley this past April, my credit wasn't up to par for the bike I was interested in so the dealer asked if I could get someone to co-sign. I talked it over with my father and he agreed to co-sign for the loan.
My concern is that he is listed as the primary borrower and I'm listed as the co borrower. Even though our paperwork that we have from the dealer and financials have me listed as primary, and him co-borrower. The bike is registered to me and I'm making payments on it but all financials are tied to him. With only his name on it.

1. Is that legal? Can they do that without asking?
2. is there anything I can do to fix it.

We have copies of everything we signed, and nowhere does any of it have him listed as primary. It all has me listed as the primary borrower.

Comment: The simple fact is that it doesn't matter who is primary and co-borrower. You are both equally on the hook for the money. Primary is just the person they will go after first. If neither of you pays the note it will trash both of your credit. Never do co-signing.

Comment: I've seen this response multiple times in other posts. Paying the loan isnt the issue. What it comes down to is in my state an auto loan the primary loan holder is there owner of the vehicle. So when this vehicle is paid off. The motorcycle will be in my father's name and will have to be transferred to me. Again there are ways for this to be done and not the end of the world. But more steps that will be necessary and more fees. Also there is no paperwork that I can obtain that states I'm paying on a loan because my name is nowhere to be seen. Other than on my credit report.

Comment: I think if the loan shows up on your credit report, then you're listed someone as a borrower.

Comment: It looks from your comments like this could be a very jurisdiction-dependent issue. Could you please [edit] your question to add the appropriate tag(s) to indicate where in the world you are?

Answer (score 6):

> Is that legal? Can they do that without asking?

It probably is (questions of "what is legal" are usually tied to a specific jurisdiction) and it probably doesn't matter. You're **both** responsible for the loan.

> is there anything I can do to fix it.

Nothing to fix, just pay it off. If you don't - they **will** go after your father and trash his credit, that's the whole point of getting a co-signer.

Comment: I've seen this response multiple times in other posts. Paying the loan isnt the issue. What it comes down to is in my state an auto loan the primary loan holder is there owner of the vehicle. So when this vehicle is paid off. The motorcycle will be in my father's name and will have to be transferred to me. Again there are ways for this to be done and not the end of the world. But more steps that will be necessary and more fees. Also there is no paperwork that I can obtain that states I'm paying on a loan because my name is nowhere to be seen. Other than on my credit report.

Comment: @MichaelV what state is that?